# pthread_posix_mutex - unable to achieve functionality

Tags: c, pthreads, ipc, mutex, atomic

**SYSTEM:**

```
Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-57-generic-pae #87-Ubuntu i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Here below is a simple to achieve atomicity between two threads which i am not able to observe

**mutex_example.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
pthread_mutex_t mut;

void* routine(void* ptr)
{
int ret;
sleep(1);
pthread_detach(pthread_self());
ret=pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
if(ret!=0)
 perror("mutex lock at t1\n");

printf("Thread1 CC\n");

ret=pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
if(ret!=0)
 perror("mutex unlock at t1\n");

}

int
main(void)
{
int ret;
pthread_t tid;
char* string="hello";
ret=pthread_create(&tid,NULL,routine,string);
if(ret!=0)
 perror("thread Creation\n");

ret=pthread_mutex_init(&mut,NULL);//mutex init
if(ret!=0)
 perror("mutex Init at main thread\n");

ret=pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
if(ret!=0)
 perror("mutex lock at main thread\n");

printf("before 10sec sleep in main thread\n");
sleep(10);
printf("after 10sec sleep in main thread\n");

ret=pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
if(ret!=0)
 perror("mutex unlock at main thread\n");

}
```

**Expected Output:**
if main thread starts first

```
before 10sec sleep in main thread
after 10sec sleep in main thread
Thread1 CC
```

**Observed Output:**

```
before 10sec sleep in main thread
Thread1 CC
after 10sec sleep in main thread
```

how come the mutex that is already locked when sees one more lock should block until its unlocked,in a sense its not even working as a semaphore,while i also tried one more thing of unlocking in other thread but by principle a mutex can be locked and unlocked by same process am i missing some thing like attributes ???

**EDIT1**:

GCC compilation output with the command `gcc -v -o example example.c -lpthread`

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'example' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/cc1 -quiet -v -imultilib . -imultiarch i386-linux-gnu example.c -quiet -dumpbase example.c -mtune=generic -march=i686 -auxbase example -version -fstack-protector -o /tmp/cczkbCP4.s
GNU C (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) version 4.6.3 (i686-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.3, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.1.0-p3, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/i386-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed
 /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) version 4.6.3 (i686-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.3, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.1.0-p3, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 09c248eab598b9e2acb117da4cdbd785
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'example' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 as --32 -o /tmp/ccUe328u.o /tmp/cczkbCP4.s
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/:/lib/i386-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'example' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/collect2 --sysroot=/ --build-id --no-add-needed --as-needed --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -z relro -o example /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib -L/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../.. /tmp/ccUe328u.o -lpthread -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

**EDIT 2:**

*implementation error identified :* thread is been created  before the mutex is initialized

*updates:*

1.`detach` is removed in newly formed thread(instead main thread uses `join`)

2.change in objective:newly created thread tries to `unlock` the `mutex` which is acquired by main thread(to test `mutex` functionality) up on which the new thread should be in waiting state for the main thread to release the lock after 10 second sleep

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
pthread_mutex_t mut;

void* routine(void* ptr)
{
int ret;
sleep(1);

ret=pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
if(ret!=0)
 perror("mutex lock at t1\n");

printf("Thread1 CC\n");

}

int
main(void)
{
int ret;
pthread_t tid;
char* string="hello";

ret=pthread_mutex_init(&mut,NULL);//mutex init
if(ret!=0)
 perror("mutex Init at main thread\n");

ret=pthread_create(&tid,NULL,routine,string);
if(ret!=0)
 perror("thread Creation\n");

ret=pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
if(ret!=0)
 perror("mutex lock at main thread\n");

printf("before 10sec sleep in main thread\n");
sleep(10);
printf("after 10sec sleep in main thread\n");

ret=pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
if(ret!=0)
 perror("mutex unlock at main thread\n");

pthread_join(tid,NULL);

}
```

**Ouput being observed :**

```
before 10sec sleep in main thread
Thread1 CC
after 10sec sleep in main thread
```

Still the objective is not achieved !! how the other thread is able to unlock the mutex acquired by main thread ???

Comment: If omit that you create thread before mutex was locked (so, thread can use this mutex first) this joke result comes because printf is buffered. You can use unbuffered fprintf(stderr, "") or set buffer to NULL: setbuf(stdout, NULL);

Comment: @IvanIvanov anyways the '\n' are trying to flush the buffers,any how i have tried as you said,and also updated the code in regard to issue of  thread creation prior to mutex init

Comment: Well, new update version now doesn't work properly on my computer, however first worked nice.)

Comment: Add mutex_lock to task function and put mutex_unlock to end. Now it works as before.

Comment: @IvanIvanov here my intention is not to achieve atomicity instead i want to check mutex functionality,a mutex is different from semaphore .process or thread which locks the resource can only unlock it but not others.

Comment: @IvanIvanov the first one was trying to achieve atomicity so it succeded but the second update which is the actual question is not working,is there anything to do with the attributes

Comment: You can't unlock the mutex from the child thread when it hasn't been locked by that thread, that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield it may not make sense note that the key advantage between the mutex and a sema one would expect is mutex according to its principle can only be unlocked by the locked one ,so i am trying to check mutex functionality according to the principle of statement of mutex and i achieved it,i have posted the answer,have a look

Comment: You could try `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`, and make sure that you give `-pthread` to the compiler as well as the linker.  (This is pure voodoo, I'm afraid, but since something wierd is going on here, I think it's worth a try.)

Comment: @gmch that did not made any difference i tried with both,what actually is the difference between both,i dont find any difference usually linkable shared objects need this prefix of l i believe,sorry if i am wrong

Comment: What the difference is between `-pthread` and `-lpthread`, is A Good Question.  The only thing I can find is folklore which says that `-pthread` tells the compiler and linker to do whatever is required to produce a pthreaded program, where `-lpthread` (clearly) just specifies another library.  (Note that `-pthread` takes the place of `-lpthread` for the linker.)  The `-pthread` option is not listed in the gcc documentation for i386 or x86_64 -- but I know it works, because I use it (without `-lpthread`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so as i was thinking its true there is some thing to tweak with the mutex attributes while we work with this kind of operations

there are three types of attempts that should be avoided for undefined situations

1. A single thread may not lock the same mutex twice.
2. A thread may not unlock a mutex that it doesn’t currently own (i.e., that it did
   not lock).
3. A thread may not unlock a mutex that is not currently locked.

the man page of pthread_mutex_lock defines about types of mutex that we can use with attributes

```
If  the  mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL, deadlock detection shall not be provided. 
Attempting to relock the mutex causes deadlock.If a thread attempts to unlock a mutex
that it has not locked or a mutex which is unlocked, undefined behavior results.

If the mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK, then error checking shall be provided.
If a thread attempts to relock a mutex  that  it has  already  locked,  an  error  shall
be returned. If a thread attempts to unlock a mutex that it has not locked or a mutex
which is unlocked, an error shall be returned.

If the mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE, then the mutex shall maintain the concept
of a lock count. When  a  thread  successfully acquires  a mutex for the first time, the
lock count shall be set to one. Every time a thread relocks this mutex, the lock count
shall be incremented by one. Each time the thread unlocks the mutex, the lock count
shall be decremented by one. When the lock count reaches zero,  the mutex shall become
available for other threads to acquire. If a thread attempts to unlock a mutex that it
has not locked or a mutex which is unlocked, an error shall be returned.

If the mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT, attempting to recursively lock the mutex
results  in  undefined  behavior.  Attempting  to unlock the mutex if it was not locked 
by the calling thread results in undefined behavior. Attempting to unlock the mutex if 
it is not locked results in undefined behavior.
```

so i should provide the attribute of `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK` for checking whether the mutex not owned by it is being unlocked or not,if done so the checking with errno being `EPERM`

you can make use of the pthread_mutexattr_xx functions to set and init the atributes below code may help

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<errno.h>


pthread_mutex_t mut;

void* routine(void* ptr)
{
int ret;
//sleep(4);
ret=pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
if(ret!=0)
{
 errno=ret;
 perror("mutex unlock at t1\n");
 if(errno==EPERM)
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
}
fprintf(stderr,"Thread1 CC\n");

//pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
}

int
main(void)
{
int ret;
pthread_t tid;
char* string="hello";
pthread_mutexattr_t  attr;

ret=pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);//mutex attr init
if(ret!=0)
{
 errno=ret;
 perror("mutex attr Init at main thread\n");
}
ret=pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr,PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK);//mutex typeset
if(ret!=0)
{
 errno=ret;
 perror("mutex typeset Init at main thread\n");
}
ret=pthread_mutex_init(&mut,&attr);//mutex init
if(ret!=0)
{
 errno=ret;
 perror("mutex Init at main thread\n");
}
ret=pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);//attr no longer needed
if(ret!=0)
{
 errno=ret;
 perror("mutex attr destory at main thread\n");
}
ret=pthread_create(&tid,NULL,routine,string);
if(ret!=0)
{
 errno=ret;
 perror("thread Creation\n");
}

ret=pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
if(ret!=0)
{
 errno = ret;
 perror("mutex lock at main thread\n");
}
fprintf(stderr,"before 10sec sleep in main thread\n");
sleep(10);
fprintf(stderr,"after 10sec sleep in main thread\n");

ret=pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
if(ret!=0)
{
 errno = ret;
 perror("mutex unlock at main thread\n");
}
pthread_join(tid,NULL);
}
```

note that the main objective was to see the behaviour of a mutex when its locked or unlocked by non-owners of that particular mutex which are overcomed in edit2 and final answer respectively any editions are appreciated

Answer (score 2):

With threads it's always worth wondering what happens if a given thread stops running for a "long time" in between two statements (or sequence points, if we want to get technical about it).

In this case:

1. if the main thread stops after creating the thread1, then thread1
   can arrive at `pthread_mutex_lock()` before the mutex has been
   initialised.
2. if the main thread stops after initialising the mutex, then thread1 could run to completion before the main thread locks the mutex.
3. if thread1 stops at any time, and the main thread runs to completion, then the entire process will exit... whether thread1 is ready for it or not.

Of these (1) and (2) are perhaps theoretical -- given the `sleep(1)` in thread1 -- but you just know you are in trouble when the behaviour you want depends on the odd `sleep()`!  On the other hand, (3) is definitely a cause for concern.

Also, checking the return code on all the `pthread_xxx()` calls is good, but they don't set `errno`, so `perror()` will print a message, but won't tell you what the error was (you need to `errno = ret ;` to achieve that).

However, this doesn't explain why thread1 has apparently acquired the mutex when the main thread apparently owns it.

The `stdio` stuff is defined to be thread-safe, and with line-buffered `stdout` and printing complete lines... I too would expect the output to appear as you expect it to.

So... not a complete answer (sorry)... but if I were you I would get rid of the `pthread_detach()` and add a `pthread_join()` to main (just before it exits) and see if it still behaves oddly.  (And, for completeness, initialise the mutex before creating thread1.)

I assume this is linked with `-pthread`.

I have tried the code as posted, and it works as one would expect (3.14.9 Linux kernel, x86_64, gcc 4.8.3, glibc 2.18).  (I got a warning that `sleep()` was implicitly declared... but that didn't stop it working.)  So I am forced to the conclusion that there is some snafu in the way stuff is compiled/linked on your machine, or some issue with the libraries, or some other exotic system specific problem.

Comment: thanks for your response i tried to view all of your points and tried to update the code but still i am not able to achieve the objective of using mutex